# PHP cURL is not capturing all ASP.NET Cookies

Tags: php, asp.net, cookies, curl

Trying to automate login to a ASP.NET site using PHP & cURL but running into a cookie problem.

When I check in the browser, initial login page stores 5 cookies. Which are ASP.NET_SessionId, __utma, __utmb, __utmc & __utmz

When this page is accessed via cURL the cookie file is storing only one cookie: "ASP.NET_SessionId"

I referred to many posts & tried all kinds of cURL option combinations returning the same result.

I don't know how ASP.NET cookies work or differ from PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my php code:

```
$cookie_file_path = "tmp/cookie.txt";
$LOGINURL         = "https://godaddy.com"; 
$agent            = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);
$content = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

echo '<textarea style="width:1000px; height:300px">'.$content.'</textarea>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__utma, __utmb, __utmc & __utmz are all Google Analytics cookies stored by javascript, thus  being created client side.

So no way of processing them through cURL / PHP

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I was concerned with these cookies because I was not able to login with post data (next step).

Comment: I doubt they will be checking on analytics cookies. You should look  for hidden input fields being required, i can see they got __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION for example. (https://myaccount.amsoil.com)

Comment: I got that included in the post data… still I am not able to login. Since this is not a cookie problem, maybe I should create another post with the actual code I am using to figure out why I could not login.

Comment: @Jeppe but how to get ASP Session ID?

Comment: @Volatil3 This can be accessed directly from $_COOKIE['ASP.NET_SessionId'] - Read more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php